# The property cannot be configured as a navigation property - Entity Framework

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I am new to .net and entity framework. I have two models `User` and `Request` and they look as follows.

User.cs

```
    [Table("User")]
    public class User
    {
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int UserId { get; set; }

        public DateTime CreateDate { get; set; }

        public bool IsActive { get; set; }
    }
```

Request.cs

```
    [Table("Request")]
    public class Request
    {
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int RequestId { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("UserId")]
        public int UserId { get; set; }

        public string Reason { get; set; }

        public DateTime CreateDate { get; set; }
    }
```

Here is my Linq query:

```
var requests = (from req in dbcontext.Request
                join user in dbcontext.User on req.UserId equals user.UserId
                select new RequestOptionsDTO 
                { 
                    RequestId = req.RequestId, 
                    UserId = req.UserId, 
                    Reason = req.Reason, 
                    CreateDate = req.CreateDate, 
                    UserIsActive = user.IsActive 
                }).ToList();
```

It is a simple query but I keep getting the following error:

```
The property 'UserId' cannot be configured as a navigation property. 
The property must be a valid entity type and the property should have a non-abstract getter and setter.
For collection properties the type must implement ICollection<T> where T is a valid entity type.
```

I have ran the same query in a ASP.Net Core Web API project which is using Entity Framework Core v3.1 and it is working fine.

The problem is the same query won't work on a console app which is using Entity Framework 6.

Can someone please help me with this?

Comment: EF6 or EF Core?

Comment: @IvanStoev EF6. I have ran the same query in a ASP.Net Core Web API project which is using Entity Framework Core v3.1 and it is working fine. The problem is the same query won't work on a console app which is using Entity Framework 6. I have updated the same in my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is not the query, but the model (the model is lazily initialized on first query execution, so you'll get the same exception for any query from that DbContext).

The actual cause of the issue is the invalid `ForeignKey` attribute. When applied to FK property (as in your scenario) it expects the **name** of the associated navigation property. And when applied to navigation property it expects the name of the FK property.

In this case, "UserId" is not a valid name of a navigation property in `Request` class, which is what the error message is trying to tell you in their own unique way.

EF Core simply ignores such inconsistencies while EF6 throws exception as it should. Both don't allow defining relationship w/o navigation properties with data annotations. However EF Core allows defining such relationship fluently, while EF requires at leas one navigation property.

So in order to define a FK relationship you need to add at least

```
public User User { get; set; }
```

to `Request`, or

```
public ICollection<Request> Requests { get; set; }
```

to `User`, or both. In either case, no additional data annotations / fluent configuration is needed.

And of course don't forget to remove the invalid `ForeignKey` attribute.

Comment: I have tried your solution but I am still getting the same error.

Comment: Well, I've tried it in my clean test EF6 environment before posting, and the error is gone. Make sure you have deleted the `[ForeignKey("UserId")]` line. Also check the other entities for similar attribute - as I said, the query doesn't matter, you have to clean up the model. If needed, start with a clean project, add classes/attributes/configuration until `Add-Migration` command completes successfully. There is nothing more I can do - the error has been reproduced and fixed.

Comment: BTW, once I removed `[ForeignKey("UserId")]` line, I am getting a similar error but it is complaining about the `RequestId`. `The property 'RequestId' cannot be configured as a navigation property. The property must be a valid entity type and the property should have a non-abstract getter and setter. For collection properties the type must implement ICollection<T> where T is a valid entity type.`

Comment: "Btw" just proves that the original problem is fixed and now you are getting similar, but *different* error. Just do the same - find `[ForeignKey("RequestId")]` in code, remove it and add navigation property etc. Repeat that for all similar errors - he exception message is telling the invalid `ForeignKey` attribute (`UserId`, `RequestId`), all you need is to find them and apply the above solution, which for obvious reason is covering only the original post issue, as per SO rules.

Comment: That fixed it! I have just started working on .net and I am new to most of the terminology. Sorry for not understanding it earlier and thank you for explaining it in detail! Thanks again!!